# Why does a shared preference contains something I haven't put?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, contains

Problem solved.

The shared preference should contains anything before I close it for the first time but the error says IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. How come?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("myfile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.commit();
    if(pref.contains("key")){
    List.addAll(pref.getStringSet("key", null));
    };         
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(size>0){
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    set1.addAll(List);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("myfile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("key", set1);
    editor.commit();
    };
}
```

I'm not sure what to look for at logcat so I just paste it all.

06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vocabulary/com.example.vocabulary.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.example.vocabulary.MainActivity.PrintWords(MainActivity.java:70)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.example.vocabulary.MainActivity.ShitsToDoWhenCodeSucks(MainActivity.java:118)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at com.example.vocabulary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625):     ... 11 more

Comment: *Where* are you getting that exception? Which line?

Comment: I believe it's the first if sentence because if I delete it the rest of app runs perfectly

Comment: You should look at the exception - it will show which line caused the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure which line it is. What should I do to check?

Comment: As I said, look at the exception. The stack trace should give you lots of information.

Comment: Okay, so I looked up about the error information if gave me but still can't see where is the problem

Comment: Well based on the stack trace, it looks like it's line 70 of MainActivity.java. You should start following Java naming conventions for methods, by the way - and prefer rather more professional names than "ShitsToDoWhenCodeSucks"

Comment: Okay! But I don't get it. Line 70 is about another arraylist

Comment: Wow! It is because of another arraylist!

Comment: I figured it out! It's because I tried to test if shared preference works so I forgot to take care of the another arraylist which corresponds to the one I used to test

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thank you, but may I ask how can you tell the problem is line 70? Also, thanks for introducing me the Java naming conventions. Incidentally, can you answer me officially so I could chose you as the answer? It helped a lot, really. I've constructed everything else last week but stuck here for another week. Thanks again!

Comment: This line of the stack trace was the key one: "06-05 13:05:30.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1625): at com.example.vocabulary.MainActivity.PrintWords(MainActivity.java:70)" - it's really important to learn to read stack traces. It's not really clear to me what kind of answer I'd give, as all I've done is help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Well anyway, still I am now conscious of these tools. And among the many walked by, only so few stoped to oblige. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a preferences file named 'myfile' there?

If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).

Comment: What I asked was, do you have an xml file for preferences with a <Preference android:defaultValue="0" android:key="key"/>

Comment: Otherwise, in your onCreate, write as -->   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); editor.putString("key", "defaultval");
    editor.commit();

Comment: Also, plz checkout your 'List'. did you mean an ArrayList object?